# JavaScript catch Internal Server Error 500

Tags: javascript, error-handling, runtime-error, try-catch, internal-server-error

I currently have a script that I use to remotely restart "worker" objects by accessing the back end of their configuration.

I run this script in console in Google Chrome as I do not have access to the actual code base.  When I run the script in Google Chrome and the worker # (see below) does exist the script runs great and does successfully restart the worker.

The trouble is that when the script tries to restart a worker that does not exist, or the function times out, the script will stop running and I get " 500 Internal Server Error."  I want the script to keep running and restart the other workers that I feed into the script despite this error.

I have tried adding try{} catch(e){} before and after several different parts of the script but have not been successful.  Is there any way I can try to rewrite this code or any other method I can use to ignore this internal server error and have the script continue to run?? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Run Script via console in Google Chrome via worker page

    var workerIds = [*ALL WORKER IDS ENTERED HERE COMMA SEPERATED*]

    var WorkerSetUp = company.module("Configuation").WorkerSetUp;

    function restartWorkersRecur(){

     if(workerIds.length > 0) {
       var wid = workerIds.pop();
       console.log("Going to restart: " + wid);
       window.setTimeout(function(){
           restartWorkerRecur(wid);
           }, 5000);
        }
     else{
        console.log("Done");
        }
    }

    function restartWorkerRecur(wid){
        var wmModel = new WorkerSetUp;
        wmModel.id = wid;
        wmModel.fetch({success: function(model){
            if(!model.get("KillFlag")){
                   model.set("KillFlag", true);
                model.save([], {success: function(model){
                    model.set("KillFlag", false);
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        model.save([], {success: function(model){
                            console.log("Finished restarting: " + model.id);
                            restartWorkersRecur();
                        }});                   
                    }, 1000);
                }});
            }
        }});
    }

    restartWorkersRecur();
```

*Again, I do not have direct access to the code base.  I do have special authorization though that allows me to pull worker Id's and then essentially restart them via Google Chrome.  I have obviously changed a few names of the variables.  The script does in fact work great when the worker exists. I just want it to keep running if the worker does not. If there is any other information I can provide please let me know, and any help would be greatly appreciated.  To repeat I also have already tried using basic try and catch statements with no luck.

Comment: A 500 error is a **server** error. If that `WorkerSetup` code is throwing a client-side exception when it detects that, then you can use a simple JavaScript `try`/`catch` to keep it from stopping your whole script.

Comment: It's probably that `wmodel.fetch()` call that's throwing the exception.

Comment: So you suggest adding try catch to the wmodel.fetch() logic? ps thank you for your help